# How to register a tool with MarkLogic?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

We have developed a XQuery review Tool and we would like to register it with MarkLogic site. Could somebody guide us to register the tool in MarkLogic?

Comment: Contact Eric Bloch from Marklogic. You can guess his email address.. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

See http://developer.marklogic.com/code , which will instruct you to send questions about contributing to [community-requests@marklogic.com](http://mailto%3acommunity-requests@marklogic.com).